# How do i call the Spree Api from a spree installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, e-commerce, spree

I have inherited a running spree Commerce website and need to work with its API. I have tried to access through URL [websitename]/api/ and api.[websitename].com but don't think I'm taking the right approach here.

Please, I want to know, does the API not come bundled when spree is installed, or does it have to be installed separately.

I've searched through Google and can find any instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much in the way of documentation for it but there's a rubygem page: https://rubygems.org/gems/spree_api and some API docs here: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/summary.html

I believe you can enable it by simply adding the following to your gemfile:

```
gem "spree_api"
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I'll check compatibility with my current installation